# Trying to checkout another azure repository

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a another repository in my Azure project called `secondaryRepo`.  I am trying to checkout it with this pipeline file:

```
    pool:
      name: 'default'

    resources:         
      repositories:
      - repository: secondaryRepo
        type: git
        name: secondaryRepo

    steps:
    - checkout: secondaryRepo
```

I get the error `Checkout of repository 'secondaryRepo' is not supported. Only 'self' and 'none' are supported.`

According to [this,](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/d1771eacc9a73bdbed3a0440b1e1eabedfe1e41f/design/pipeline-resources.md#examples-3) I should be able to check out this secondary repository.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is not supported currently. I found a smiliar github [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/103).

According to another [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/104), it mentioned that the examples in this repository are speculative, designs, and future features

> The docs are canonical and correct. As Ashok says, the examples in this repository are speculative, designs, and future features.